# why compiler doesn't stop iterating while loop

Tags: python-3.x

I made a program to print pyramid using * with my own way but whenever i run my program on compiler the program gets executed and doesn't stop after the for loop ends its iteration,here's my program which i think should stop executing after 10  iterations.

```
a = "           "
b = ""    
for i in range(10):
    a = a[:-1]
    b = (b * i) + '*'
    print('\n')
    for k in range(i):
        print("{}{}".format(a,b), end="")
```

i am expecting the output like this:

```
                 *
                ***
               *****
              *******
             *********
            ***********
           *************
          ***************
```

Comment: How do you know the program does not stop? What do you see instead?

Comment: it runs and runs till my compiler gets slow and i had to stop it with control+c @usr2564301

Comment: I think you got something else than you intended – I printed out the *lengths* of `a` and `b` and got low numbers for `a`, but `b` goes up to 986410 characters. And that string gets printed repeatedly; as much as nine times on the last line.

Comment: but b = " " doesn't even have length greater than one,how's that possible? @usr2564301

Answer (score 1):

Your problem probably comes from your b assignation.

Let's calculate the length of b at step i (from 0 to 10) (b(n) = b(n-1)*index + 1)

> b(0) = 0*0 + 1 = 1
>
> b(1) = 1*1 + 1 = 2
>
> b(2) = 2*2 + 1 = 5
>
> b(3) = 5*3 + 1 = 16

And so on, we can see the length of b is going exponential, for instance, for `index = 10`, `len(b) = 986410`

This increasing string might make the compiler slowing down.

You might want to try this code which does not keep in memory the strings.

```
height = 10
for i in range(height):
    print(' '*(height-i-1)+'*'*(2*i+1))
```

output:

```
         *
        ***
       *****
      *******
     *********
    ***********
   *************
  ***************
 *****************
*******************
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this improved code instead:

```
a = "           "       # empty string to be attached at the front and back (length is 11)
for i in range(10):     # height of pyramid
    a = a[:-1]          # make string a bit smaller to compensate for
    b = '*' * (i*2 + 1) # the increasing amount of '*'s
    print("{}{}{}".format(a, b, a)) # prints the pyramid
```

The `len(a)` should be the height of your pyramid plus the amount of padding wanted on the last row. For example:

```
     *
    ***
   *****
  *******
```

There's 2 spaces left on the bottom row, and the height of the pyramid is 4. That means the length of `a` should be 6. Make `a` using `a = ' '*(height + padding)`